# How do I visualize multiple static Prometheus TSDB files from a single Grafana instance?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a requirement in my project where I receive multiple static TSDB files which are essentially Prometheus backups and then visualize these on Grafana using dashboards.

I am looking to understand if there is any way that using a single Prometheus data-source, I can have multiple TSDB files restored into that instance and visualized using a few custom dashboards where one can switch through the filenames on the UI which act as a variable / folder list.

I did scrub through few possibilities but didn't receive a definitive answer on if it's possible only through Prometheus or if one should bring in InfluxDB as well into the picture where these TSDBs are stored independently, and one can view each of them independently on Grafana.

Could someone please help me with any ideas on how to accomplish this? ?